# C# setOnTouchListener advice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hi guys I trying to make a virtual keyborard for a program.I made two EditText and a numerical keyboard:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


namespace SOLVER
{
    [Activity (Label = "SOLVER", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button Button1,Button2,....;
        EditText a,b;   

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            SolveButton ();

                    Button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.butonul1);
                    .....................................................
                    a = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.A);
                    b= FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.B);

            a.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                ButtonClick (a);
            };
        }

        private void ButtonClick ( EditText x )
        {
        Button1.Click += delegate {
        x.Text = "1";
             };
        }       
    }
}
```

But if I click on the EditText by more than one time it will show me the nr 1 by number of clicks.

I try to change

```
    private void ButtonClick ( EditText x )
    {
    Button1.Click += delegate {
    x.Text = "1";
         };
```

with:

```
    private void ButtonClick ( EditText x )
    {
    Button1.Click -= delegate {
    x.Text = "1";
         };
```

And the program don't show anything in the EditBox.
And finally I think to switch with the function setOnTouchListener like this:

```
    Button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
            {
                x.Text = "1";
            }
        });
```

And I get two errors:

-expected } at the second line.
-A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods. at the last line.

I forgot to mention that I use Xamarin.If you can tell me what I am doing wrong or other idea please tell me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have placed this snippet:

```
Button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
            {
                x.Text = "1";
            }
        });
```

outside of your class/namespace. Check the curly braces and make sure that the code is actually inside your MainActivity class.

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem?

Comment: @user3836246 No, it's an assumption based on limited information about your code, and experience with that error message in the past. It's a reasonable guess.